# In MS Word 2010: Change tracking: how can I permanently set color of my tracked changes to red?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, change-tracking

Assume a user that use change tracking a lot on different computers on a lot of documents.

Can I go to MS Word options and permanently, for ever, set that user "johnk" will always have red color assigned to his tracked changes. (for all documents, for all years, forever).

(editing people always have some sort of identifier, so mine could be johnk and that ID would always be of same color (e.g., blue)

Comment: I wont put this as an answer an I'm not 100% sure however I believe if you was to edit the normal.dot file and change the font then re-save it will be the default font moving forward...

Comment: I am not worried about the font (e.g., Times New Roman). Only the color matters. On monday - my edits are blue, then on thursday - my edits are suddenlty orange. The change of color is frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research - I am concluding that it is not possible.
Hopefully this annoying problem will be solved in future versions of MS Word.

Comment: Can you cite some research for others?

Comment: Well it was google search and exploring the menus. Absence of solution X is hard to document (as opposed the opposite)